# BCryptPasswordEncoder Seems resource consuming a lot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In a Spring based authentication in an app, It seems BCryptPasswordEncoder is very slow and consuming the CPU power very highly while user authentication happens on each request.

This is noticed as an critical performance bottleneck (TPS) in the web application.

Are there any alternatives having good performance with considerable security to be used as the password encoder for authentication ?

Comment: How exactly did you configure the encoder?

Answer (score 5):

If it's hard for your CPU it's also hard for the password cracker - and that's what you want.

You could consider caching the authentication result. That would be safer alternative to changing your hashing algorithm.

Comment: Great, that is what I already did,  caching the hashed value and match if it exist.